# An arrays decryption

Tags: java, encryption, substring, grouping

I wanna decode my crypted arrays. We know that the numbers are coding 1 to 9. If the result is codding by 1, in the substring we won't have more than nine ones and nothing more, but we have three examples with the results:

```
byte[][] A  = new byte[][] { { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
{ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 } }
```

Result: 43211

```
byte[][] C = new byte[][] { {}, {},
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 }, {},
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, {}, { 1, 1 }, { 1 }, {}, { 0 },
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, {} };
```

Result: 1233

```
byte[][] A = new byte[][] {
{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
```

Result: 332132

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should explain your problem clearly. I understood nothing from your question.

Comment: Sure! I wanna decode my crypted arrays. We know that the numbers are coding 1 to 9. If the result is codding by 1, in the substring we won't have more than nine ones. 'new byte[][] { { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, 
               { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
               { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 } }'  For example the result of this array is: 43211 and my idea to solve this problem is to have substring like this: 0: 1, 1: 4, 3:0... But I don't know that is the best way to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[][] A = new byte[][] {
            { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
            { 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } };
String result = "";
int counter = 0;
for (byte[] arr : A) {
    for (byte b : arr) {
        if (b == 1)
            counter++;
        else {
            if (counter > 0)
                result += counter;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
if (counter > 0)
    result += counter;
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Wow, what a easy way! I wanted to do too much :)

Comment: @mr.Papaver Glad I could help.